# In order to make your app's UI compatible with all the devices like tablets,phones or watches which unit is preferred in android?

Tags: android

I have used dp in my xml.
but it's not giving me an accurate UI.

Comment: Did you actually read the android documentation; even for a bit ? https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html gives some info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure, **dp** is the most adequat unit to accomplish that goal.
There in addition to that, you have to define several **values** folders where you define dimensions for scaling tablets or phones.
E.g. define two **values** folders like:

```
values-large
values-xlarge
```

Now define a **dimen.xml** file inside this folders, where you can put your measurements in (unit dp) for the corresponding screensize.
Define a measurement like this:

```
<dimen name="value1">17dp</dimen>
```

Then embedd this sizes in your layout xml, like:

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/value1"
```

Depending on the screensize, the system will load the correct measurements from this folders, e.g. if you have a screen size **large** only the defined values in folder **values-large** will be loaded.
For more information, also have a look at https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html

Answer (score 0):

`dp` is the preferred measurement size in Android.

For defining text size use `sp`, as it would preserve user font settings, for example, if user has set text as larger in its device settings, TextView with 12sp would show bigger text than TextView with 12dp text.

You can read more here: https://material.google.com/layout/units-measurements.html

Though not sure what you mean by "accurate UI" :)