# fixed height & width of image view

Tags: android, android-layout, responsive-design, imageview

I am working on android app which fetch data from **API** and show in recycler view. I don't have any idea about design, and someone told me to not to assign fix value to **height width** and if I don't assign fix value then how should I design layout to look same on all android devices ? 
I want responsiveness, any guidliness?

1. Is it ok if I assign constant value to the height and width of image view.
2. If I open the app in tablet, will it show image according to screen size or the image will be of smaller size ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In order to make your app's UI compatible with all the devices like tablets,phones or watches which unit is preferred in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38223308/in-order-to-make-your-apps-ui-compatible-with-all-the-devices-like-tablets-phon)

Answer (score 5):

There are various solution for that like Percentage layout/LinearLayout with weight /Coordinator layout .

But I always use SDP(standard density pixel) for that , it will make your UI fit to different size of screen .
**Libreary**
https://github.com/intuit/sdp.

and just use it like this

```
android:layout_height="@dimen/_10sdp"
```

Comment: yes this one is correct This will help you to adjust the size in most cases

Comment: @R7G I am gonna try it

Answer (score 1):

1. it is not OK to assign fix value to imageview because it will take same size in all device whether it is small device or it is large device. And also use **android:adjustViewBounds="true"** with ImageView.
2. first one is for margin and padding.
   **implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'**

second one is for text size only.
**implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.5'**

Comment: [this design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52401304/layout-items-adjustment-issue/52402738?noredirect=1#comment91749451_52402738)

Comment: GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

adapter = new Adapter(context;
 recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

In adapter 
single item root layout .
cv_bg.getLayoutParams().width = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/2;

**It is the only hint...**